# Azure Authentication sending SMS confirmation

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm using Azure Authentication in a mobile app, using the azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova plugin.

Recently some user have trouble logging in. Some are even receiving SMS to confirm their mobile number, still without actually being able to complete the login.

They can still log in like normal on other services (such as their computer at work) - but when using this login for our app is causing problems.

It's not consistent - some users are having troubles and receiving SMS, while others are not.

Any suggestions what may cause this, and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

It appears like some users that are trying to sign into your application have Multi-Factor Authentication set up.

Please take a look at the following Article: [Multi-Factor Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/multi-factor-authentication/multi-factor-authentication)

I am not an expert in the MFA scenarios, but it appears that there are custom SDKs that you might need to integrate with your application to fully support signing in those users: [Multi-Factor Authentication SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/multi-factor-authentication/multi-factor-authentication-sdk)

Let me know if this helps, or if you have a more specific question, let me know and I can try and find the right person to help you.